# the bones can't be mirrored and also a lot of problems arise

Tags: mirror

When I do bone binding, two problems arise:

1. Mirror question, as shown in Figure 1: (I tried to search for the answer , and someone told me: to edit mode, R - Z - 90)(and i already named)
   [image]
   [image]
   [image][image][image]
2. So there is a problem as shown in Figure 2, and the bones are completely messed up
   thank you for your advice!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Symmetrize operation will use the origin as center. For the moment the origin is not correctly located. To correct that, select a spine bone in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*:

[image]

Then back to *Object* mode, right click and *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*:

[image]